# How to submit login info securely from non-ssl wrapped page?

Tags: http, ssl, https

In my webpages that are not SSL wrapped, I have a login form. Users can enter their username and password and submit the info in that login form to authenticate.

The action specified in the login form is https:///login. Is this enough for the into to be encrypted or do both pages have to be ssl wrapped?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough.

This way, an attacker can not get the login user and password because the browser is sending them encrypted. **BUT** if after the login you revert to plain http, an attacker may sniff the session cookie and use that to impersonate your users. See [firesheep](http://www.codebutler.com/firesheep/) for details.

Comment: Thank you much for the additional info. I will check it out.